# Locked myself out of windows server - no user has remote access anymore

Tags: windows-server-2003

I never thought I would be that unfocused but apparently I did... I disabled the Administrator user and created a new user with password.  Unfortunatly I forgot to add this user to the remote access users group.
Now I cannot login anymore to this server, which is 1500 miles away, btw.
Luckily (?) we have other servers in the subnet.

I tried accessing it via regedit -> connect to remote computer; but I couldn't connect to the server with the credentials of the new (and only) user.

They are all Windows 2003 R2 Servers.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: assume the sever is stand-alone & not in a domain?

Comment: indeed! not in a domain

Answer (score 4):

I would attempt to make a connection to the servers admin$ share with the newly created credentials and then use compmgmt.msc to add the user to the necessary group to allow remote desktop connections.

1. From the comment prompt, run net use \ \ {ServerName}\admin$ /user:{ServerName}{NewlyCreatedUsername}
2. Enter the password for the new user
3. Run compmgmt.msc
4. Right-click on Computer Management (Local), click Connect to another computer
5. Type the name of the server, click OK
6. Add the newly created user to the Remote Desktop Users group

You should then be able to connect to the server.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I've been trying that but I get "the networkname cannot be found"
I guess they are not in the same workgroup nor I know the exact computername/servername ; only the IP

Comment: You can use the IP address in place of the server name above.

Comment: I kept on trying but whatever I try I get an error:

C:\Documents and Settings\immserveruser>net use  \\212.112.2xx.61\admin$
System error 67 has occurred.

The network name cannot be found.

I tried IP, nslookup FQDN, etc

Comment: now I get system error 5 (network) ....

Comment: It seems as if you are connecting to the server now, but the credentials are possibly incorrect.  Are you entering the option /user: {ServerName}\{username} and then being prompted for a password?

Comment: Yes, it does prompt for a password; when I enter a wrong password I get a different, logical error: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password. 
On the other hand, when entering the right one I get this error --------------------------------------------------------------- C:\Documents and Settings\IMMSERVERUSER>net use \\212.112.2xx.61\admin$ /user:21 2.112.2xx.61\immserveruser The password or user name is invalid for \\212.112.2xx.61\admin$. Enter the password for '212.112.2xx.61\immserveruser' to connect to '212.112.2xx.61': System error 5 has occurred. Access is denied. Thx in adv

Comment: Did you add the new user to the Administrators group when you created it?

Comment: probably I didn't ... :s 
Can this be undone? It is the only user left

Comment: It is quite possible that someone at the location could boot the system to a password recovery utility boot disk and enable the Administrator account, but that will take having someone at the server location. Let me know if you need further information about that process.

Comment: Indeed, that's what I did. Someone logged into the server locally